# Multiple script tags variable conflict?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple script tags in a web page.  Will having the same variable name in more than one script tag cause issues with the variables getting the wrong value from an above script tag?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var current = 0;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var current = 1;
</script>
```

Will the first current cause issues with the second occurence?

Comment: The best answer you can get from the information provided is that it will **probably** cause problems. However, if you only ever had code that was executed as it's processed (so no functions that are called later on which rely on the value of `current` being a specific value), you should be ok.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes it will**. There is only one *global execution context*, doesn't matter how many `<script>` nodes you have in your HTML markup.

So in this particular example, `current` gets initialzed on the `window` object with `0` and then gets overwritten with `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You won't ever run into a situation where code that's executed immediately after the `var current = 1` in your second `<script>` tag will be using `current` with a value other than `1`. To provide a very basic example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var current = 0;
   alert(current); // will always alert 0
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var current = 1;
   alert(current); // will always alert 1, never 0
</script>
```

That should answer the "cause issues with the variables getting the wrong value from an above script tag" aspect of the question.